# value of $_POST variable not showing up to textbox

Tags: php, html

This is not my first time of using post variables but this one's making me break my silence, just kidding, 
anyway the error showing up is

Notice: Undefined index: AgentName in C:\xampp\htdocs\s1\agent.php on line 34

my php code

```
<?php
$AgentID = null;
if (!empty($_GET['AgentID'])) {
    $AgentID = $_REQUEST['AgentID'];
}

if (null==$AgentID) {
    header("Location: agent.php");
}

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $AgentName = $_POST['AgentName'];
    $CurrentBalance = $_POST['CurrentBalance'];

    $valid = true;

    if ($valid) {
        $setsu = dbSetsuzoku();
        $setsu->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "UPDATE agentdb SET AgentName = ?, CurrentBalance=? WHERE AgentID = ?";
        $q = $setsu->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($AgentName,$CurrentBalance,$AgentID));
        $setsu = null;
        header("Location: agent.php");
    }
} else {
    $setsu = dbSetsuzoku();
    $setsu->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM agentdb where AgentID = ?";
    $q = $setsu->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($AgentID));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $AgentID = $data['AgentID'];
    $AgentName = $_POST['AgentName'];
    $CurrentBalance = $data['CurrentBalance'];
    $setsu = null;
}

?>
```

html

```
<input name="AgentName" type="text" id="agentMeiKakushi" value="<?php echo !empty($AgentName)?$AgentName:'';?>">
```

what could be mising or something?

Comment: Have you tried doing an echo on this page after requesting the post to see if the variable is populated?

Comment: other post variable works correctly? pe. 'CurrentBalance'

Comment: i did but nothing appears, what's mysterious is the input box that displays the Currentbalance does the same thing, <input name="CurrentBalance" type="text" placeholder="Current Balance" value="<?php echo isset($CurrentBalance)?$CurrentBalance:'';?>"  required /><br> ←shows up

Comment: try to `print_r($_POST)` to know what is receiving at other end

Comment: what showed up is Array ( )

Comment: is there any array element called `AgentName` ?

Comment: i think there is, isnt it the line $q->execute(array($AgentName,$CurrentBalance,$AgentID));??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem your code

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $AgentName = $_POST['AgentName'];
    $CurrentBalance = $_POST['CurrentBalance'];

    $valid = true;

    if ($valid) {
        $setsu = dbSetsuzoku();
        $setsu->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "UPDATE agentdb SET AgentName = ?, CurrentBalance=? WHERE AgentID = ?";
        $q = $setsu->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($AgentName,$CurrentBalance,$AgentID));
        $setsu = null;
        header("Location: agent.php");
    }
} else {
    $setsu = dbSetsuzoku();
    $setsu->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM agentdb where AgentID = ?";
    $q = $setsu->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($AgentID));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $AgentID = $data['AgentID'];
    $AgentName = $_POST['AgentName']; // <------ here 
    $CurrentBalance = $data['CurrentBalance'];
    $setsu = null;
}
```

on this if you declare if $_post contains data frist option, else, second (else)

4th line at the end, youh have $agentNAme = post.... here you don't have access to $_POST if posibility do you confused with $data.

Comment: why he don't have access to `$_POST` ?

Comment: on the 'if' declare:  if $_post is different to empty, contains data. on the else is the opposite, $_post don't contains data.

Comment: Oh I see! looks like my eyes have problem sometimes Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Should be rather:

```
<?php echo (isset($AgentName))?$AgentName:'';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You form should have the POST method:

```
<form method="POST" ...></form>
```